# Página inicial custom e página de blog

Tags: wordpress

Olá
Fiquei um bom tempo sem me envolver com projetos WP

Agora tive que retomar um e to meio perdido.
Tenho o seguinte cenário: o site tem o objetivo principal ser um e-commerce(woocommerce) e secundário um blog. Eu codifiquei a página incial pra mostrar produtos e abaixo, listar os últimos 4 posts. Porém eu queria poder criar um link "veja todos os posts" que leva o usuário para "/blog" onde lista todos os posts(o que seria uma página incial de blog de wordpress).
Acontece que eu tentei inúmeras combinações index.php, home.php, front-page.php(coisas que eu sei que são da hieraquia de template) e não consigo. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

lembro-me de no passado, usar front-page.php para uma página custom que eu codifiquei e home.php para o index blog. Mas não ta funcionando.

Não gostaria de usar plugins adicionais. E gostaria de me manter no código, sem muitas configurações no painel(regras do cliente).

Cada dia que passa é mais dificil achar informações avançadas sobre o wordpress no google devido a disputas semanticas com tutoriais para iniciantes.

Answer (score 0):

O template `front-page.php` é usado para exibir uma página inicial estática, o que se aplica no seu cenário de "página incial pra mostrar produtos e abaixo, listar os últimos 4 posts".

O template `home.php` é o que vai exibir os posts blog.

E o template `index.php` é aquele que será exibido se nenhum template se encaixar na requisição do usuário.

Pelo que entendi, o seu problema é com o link '"veja todos os posts" que leva o usuário para "/blog"', certo?

Para isso funcionar, você precisa:

1. Ter um template `front-page.php` com a página customizada que deseja e um template `home.php` ou `index.php` com a página de posts do blog.
2. Em `Configurações -> Leitura` no painel de administrador do WordPress, marcar as seguintes opções:

   **Sua página inicial exibe:** Uma página estática (selecionar abaixo)

   **Página inicial:** escolha uma para ser sua página inicial

   **Página de posts:** escolha uma para ser a página do seu blog. *Lembre-se de escolher `blog` como slug dessa página para que ela possa ser acessada através do endereço /blog.*
3. No link 'Veja todos os posts' você pode escrever diretamente /blog no href, mas isso é um pouco arriscado caso o administrador do site venha a alterar o slug da página do blog criada no passo anterior. Então, o melhor cenário é usar a função `get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' )` para gerar a URL da página do blog dinamicamente, à prova de alterações do usuário.